# Reading catalog file information

Tags: c#, windows, security, winapi, catalog

When you open a catalog file (.cat) in Explorer, you get a 'Security Catalog' tab with several catalog entries (that on their term list entry details). I need to **read** these entry details but I could absolutely find nothing on how to do this, let alone in C#. I don't care about verification of the catalog file, I just need to access to this information.

This is the tab and information I'm talking about.

[image: Security Catalog tab in Explorer]

Thank you!

Comment: What is a "catalog file"?

Comment: A catalog / digital signature / certificate file (with .cat extension). I have no idea how else to call it.

Comment: You need to use the WinAPI, there is no wrapper in managed code as far as I know - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380252%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#catalog_functions

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it as it looks promising.

Comment: I want to re ask this same question.

Comment: 2023 still struggling on this topic.

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651844/how-can-i-parse-catwindows-system-catalog-file-via-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

Windows Catalog files consist of a global attribute collection and per-file attribute collections which are then digitally signed and used to validate Windows driver packages during installation.

To access information stored in `.cat` files, you use Windows API from `WinTrust.dll` and `bcrypt.dll`.

An example of parsing a `.cat` file:

```
//
// © 2023 by Igor Levicki. All Rights Reserved.
//
// License : MIT NO-AI
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software
// and associated documentation files (the “Software”), to deal in the Software without restriction,
// including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense,
// and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so.
//
// Permission is not granted to use this software or any of the associated files as sample data for the
// purposes of building machine learning models.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT
// LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
// IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
// WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
// SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//

#include <Windows.h>
#include <mscat.h>
#include <WinTrust.h>
#include <mssip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wintrust.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "bcrypt.lib")

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    HCRYPTPROV hProv;

    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0)) {
        DWORD Error = GetLastError();
        if (Error == NTE_BAD_KEYSET) {
            if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET)) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    HANDLE hCat = CryptCATOpen(L"nv_disp.cat", CRYPTCAT_OPEN_EXISTING, hProv, CRYPTCAT_VERSION_1, 0);

    // Enumerate global catalog attributes (entries shown in General tab)
    CRYPTCATATTRIBUTE *pCatAttr = NULL;

    for (pCatAttr = CryptCATEnumerateCatAttr(hCat, pCatAttr); pCatAttr != NULL; pCatAttr = CryptCATEnumerateCatAttr(hCat, pCatAttr)) {
        // TODO: Do what you want with global attributes here
    }

    // Enumerate catalog members (entries shown in Security Catalog tab under Catalog Entries)
    CRYPTCATMEMBER *pMember = NULL;

    for (pMember = CryptCATEnumerateMember(hCat, pMember); pMember != NULL; pMember = CryptCATEnumerateMember(hCat, pMember)) {
        // Member ReferenceTag is essentially a hash (SHA1, SHA256, ...) of a catalog member
        wprintf(L"Reference Tag : %s\n", pMember->pwszReferenceTag);

        // EXAMPLE #1:
        // Get a specific attribute of a catalog member by name ("File" in this case represents filename)
        CRYPTCATATTRIBUTE *pFileAttr = CryptCATGetAttrInfo(hCat, pMember, L"File");
        // Get the filename
        wchar_t *FileName = (wchar_t*)pFileAttr->pbValue;

        // EXAMPLE #2:
        // Enumerate all attributes of a catalog member (entries shown in Security Catalog tab under Entry Details)
        CRYPTCATATTRIBUTE *pAttr = NULL;

        for (pAttr = CryptCATEnumerateAttr(hCat, pMember, pAttr); pAttr != NULL; pAttr = CryptCATEnumerateAttr(hCat, pMember, pAttr)) {
            // TODO: Do what you want with catalog member attributes here
        }
    }

    if (hCat != NULL) {
        CryptCATClose(hCat);
    }

    if (hProv != NULL) {
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See this link for a C# program to read a .cat file's tags and their attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56555957/get-thumbprint-value-of-security-catalog-tag-from-cat-file.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround from using the Windows Wintrust.dll is using the PowerShell to retrieve info as if you were using the security catalog program, it is kind of raw but for **reading** works great, and using the program itself visually helps. And you can use Powershell scripts to retrieve more/less info.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string catalogFilePath = "C:\\Users\\andil\\Desktop\\catstuff\\name.CAT"; 
 // Replace with your file path
    ReadCatalogInfo(catalogFilePath);
}

static void ReadCatalogInfo(string catalogFilePath)
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "powershell.exe",
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

    Process process = new Process() { StartInfo = psi };
    process.Start();
    //EXPLAINATION OF THE POWERSHELL SCRIPT
    // Store the path to the catalog file in a variable
    // Get the authenticode signature information of the catalog file
    // Display the authenticode signature information
    // Display the 'Security Catalog Tab' heading
    // Display the signer certificate information
    // Display the 'Catalog Entries' heading
    // Get the authenticode signature information of the catalog file again and format it as a table with the properties FileName, FilePath, and FileDescription
    string script = @" 
    $catalogFilePath = """ + catalogFilePath + @"""
    $catalogInfo = Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $catalogFilePath
    $catalogInfo | Format-List
    Write-Host 'Security Catalog Tab:'
    $catalogInfo.SignerCertificate | Format-List
    Write-Host 'Catalog Entries:'
    Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $catalogFilePath | Format-Table -Property FileName, FilePath, FileDescription
    ";

    // Execute the script command
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(script);
    process.StandardInput.Close();

    // Read the output and error streams
    string commandOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string errorMessage = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    process.WaitForExit();

    // Check if there was any error
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorMessage))
    {
        // Output the command output
        Console.WriteLine(commandOutput);
    }
    else
    {
        // Output the error message
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {errorMessage}");
    }
    //this is an example how you can read and manipulate the output from the PowerShell results
    // Check if the command output contains a specific tag
    if (commandOutput.Contains("1CD746A1"))
    {
        string[] outputLines = commandOutput.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (string line in outputLines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("1CD746A1"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@$"Found this line that contained the tag: {line}");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

This is my terminal output for some random .CAT hash tag part i searched and it found from a .CAT's path on my PC
[image: proof]