# get "thumbprint" value of security catalog tag from .cat file

Tags: c#, winapi, cryptography, catalog

I want to compare the hashes for every tag of 2 Security Catalog (.cat) files.

I get all tags with the CryptCATEnumerateMember function and tried to get the hashes with CryptCATEnumerateAttr, but this didn't work.

```cs
IntPtr pMemberPtr = CatalogFunctions.CryptCATEnumerateMember(hCatalog, IntPtr.Zero);            
            while (pMemberPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CRYPTCATMEMBER cdf = (CRYPTCATMEMBER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pMemberPtr, typeof(CRYPTCATMEMBER));
                IntPtr pAttributePtr = CatalogFunctions.CryptCATEnumerateAttr(hCatalog, pMemberPtr, IntPtr.Zero);
                while (pAttributePtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CRYPTCATATTRIBUTE cdfa = (CRYPTCATATTRIBUTE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pAttributePtr, typeof(CRYPTCATATTRIBUTE));
                    data.Add(cdfa.cbValue.ToString());
                    pAttributePtr = CatalogFunctions.CryptCATEnumerateAttr(hCatalog, pMemberPtr, pAttributePtr);
                }
                data.Add(cdf.pwszReferenceTag);
                pMemberPtr = CatalogFunctions.CryptCATEnumerateMember(hCatalog, pMemberPtr);
            }
//with the functions and classes:
        [DllImport("Wintrust.dll")]
        public static extern unsafe IntPtr CryptCATEnumerateMember(
            IntPtr hCatalog,
            IntPtr pPrevMember); 
        [DllImport("Wintrust.dll")]
        public static extern unsafe IntPtr CryptCATEnumerateAttr(
            IntPtr hCatalog,
            IntPtr pCatMember,
            IntPtr pPrevAttr);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class CRYPTCATATTRIBUTE {
        public uint cbStruct;
        public string pwszReferenceTag;
        public uint dwAttrTypeAndAction;
        public uint cbValue;                        
        public unsafe byte* pdValue;                
        public uint dwReserved;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class CRYPTCATMEMBER
    {
        public uint cbStruct;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pwszReferenceTag;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pwszFileName;
        public GUID gSubjectType;
        public uint fdwMemberFlags;
        public IntPtr pIndirectData;
        public uint dwCertVersion;
        public uint dwReserved;
        public IntPtr hReserved;
        public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB sEncodedIndirectData;
        public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB sEncodedMemberInfo;
    }
```

the project compiles, but pAttributePtr allways points to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me (tested on Windows 10, VS 2015, with *C:\Program Files\USBPcap\usbpcapamd64.cat* file =>

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("Wintrust.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr CryptCATOpen(string pwszFileName, int fdwOpenFlags, IntPtr hProv, int dwPublicVersion, int dwEncodingType);

        [DllImport("Wintrust.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptCATClose(IntPtr hCatalog);

        [DllImport("Wintrust.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr CryptCATEnumerateMember(IntPtr hCatalog, IntPtr pPrevMember);

        [DllImport("Wintrust.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr CryptCATEnumerateAttr(IntPtr hCatalog, IntPtr pCatMember, IntPtr pPrevAttr);

        public const int INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CRYPTCATMEMBER
        {
            public int  cbStruct;           // = sizeof(CRYPTCATMEMBER)
            public IntPtr pwszReferenceTag;
            public IntPtr pwszFileName;       // used only by the CDF APIs
            public Guid gSubjectType;       // may be zeros -- see sEncodedMemberInfo
            public int fdwMemberFlags;
            public IntPtr pIndirectData;     // may be null -- see sEncodedIndirectData
            public int dwCertVersion;      // may be zero -- see sEncodedMemberInfo
            public int dwReserved;         // used by enum -- DO NOT USE!
            public IntPtr hReserved;          // pStack(attrs) (null if init) INTERNAL!

            public CRYPT_ATTR_BLOB sEncodedIndirectData;   // lazy decode
            public CRYPT_ATTR_BLOB sEncodedMemberInfo;     // lazy decode
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CRYPT_ATTR_BLOB
        {
            public int cbData;
            public IntPtr pbData;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SIP_INDIRECT_DATA
        {
            public CRYPT_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE Data;            // Encoded attribute
            public CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER DigestAlgorithm; // Digest algorithm used to hash
            public CRYPT_HASH_BLOB Digest;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER
        {
            public IntPtr pszObjId;
            public CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB Parameters;
        }     

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CRYPT_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE
        {
            public IntPtr pszObjId;
            public CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB Value;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB
        {
            public int cbData;
            public IntPtr pbData;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CRYPT_HASH_BLOB
        {
            public int cbData;
            public IntPtr pbData;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CRYPTCATATTRIBUTE
        {
            public int cbStruct;           // = sizeof(CRYPTCATATTRIBUTE)
            public IntPtr pwszReferenceTag;
            public int dwAttrTypeAndAction;
            public int cbValue;
            public IntPtr pbValue;           // encoded CAT_NAMEVALUE struct
            public int dwReserved;         // used by enum -- DO NOT USE!
        }  


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IntPtr hCatalog = CryptCATOpen("C:\\Program Files\\USBPcap\\usbpcapamd64.cat", 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0);
            if (hCatalog != (IntPtr)INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                IntPtr pMember = IntPtr.Zero;               
                while ((pMember = CryptCATEnumerateMember(hCatalog, pMember)) != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CRYPTCATMEMBER pCRYPTCATMEMBER = (CRYPTCATMEMBER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pMember, typeof(CRYPTCATMEMBER));
                    SIP_INDIRECT_DATA pSIP_INDIRECT_DATA = (SIP_INDIRECT_DATA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pCRYPTCATMEMBER.pIndirectData, typeof(SIP_INDIRECT_DATA));

                    StringBuilder sbData = new StringBuilder();
                    IntPtr pData = pSIP_INDIRECT_DATA.Digest.pbData;
                    for (int i = 0; i < pSIP_INDIRECT_DATA.Digest.cbData; i++)
                    {
                        byte byteValue = Marshal.ReadByte(pData);
                        sbData.Append(string.Format("{0:X}", byteValue));
                        pData += 1;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Data = " + sbData.ToString());

                    IntPtr pAttr = IntPtr.Zero;
                    while ((pAttr = CryptCATEnumerateAttr(hCatalog, pMember, pAttr)) != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        CRYPTCATATTRIBUTE pCRYPTCATATTRIBUTE = (CRYPTCATATTRIBUTE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pAttr, typeof(CRYPTCATATTRIBUTE));                      
                        string sReferenceTag = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pCRYPTCATATTRIBUTE.pwszReferenceTag);
                        Console.WriteLine("\tReferenceTag = " + sReferenceTag);
                        StringBuilder sbValue = new StringBuilder();
                        IntPtr pValue = pCRYPTCATATTRIBUTE.pbValue;
                        for (int i = 0; i < pCRYPTCATATTRIBUTE.cbValue; i++)
                        {
                            byte byteValue = Marshal.ReadByte(pValue);
                            sbValue.Append(string.Format("{0:X}", byteValue));
                            pValue += 1;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\tValue = " + sbValue.ToString());
                    }                   
                }
                CryptCATClose(hCatalog);
            }
            else throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much, that is exactly what i needed :)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you were trying to accomplish by doing such a comparison, but in a security catalog **the tags themselves are the hashes** for the catalog entries.